# Great RDF visualization tools

Tags: visualization, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I want to find some great tools or styles to visualize my RDF data so that it can give viewers a shock when they access the RDF data.

The problem is that the visualization tools I get now can just generate some simple styles (node,edge...) like below:

[image: A graph sample]

They look ugly because edges take up too many spaces and nodes are too small.I don't think this kind of graphs can give viewers any different experiences from viewing sheets or tables directly.

I want to know if there are any new visualization tools or just styles that can give users really different experiences so that they can feel how invaluable linked data are...

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Hey, which tool did you use to generate the above graph visualization?

Comment: @navinpai Actually I grabbed this pic from a blog, the tool was called "Map of Knowledge" which may haven't been updated for a long time.

Comment: Can you please provide a link? Google isn't helping :(

Comment: @navinpai Sure, http://goo.gl/wRjn0a. Actually you can right click the pic and "Search Google for this image" if you use Chrome.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks. Long time Firefox user here :D

Comment: IsaViz: A Visual Authoring Tool for RDF  https://www.w3.org/2001/11/IsaViz/

Comment: List of lists of tools: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43605137/7879193

Answer (score 16):

By far the best RDF linked open data visualization tool that I've come across is LodLive:
http://en.lodlive.it/

It knows of numerous SPARQL endpoints, including DBpedia.

I've previously implemented a web based RDF authoring tool that hooks into it: https://github.com/robstewart57/discover-me-semantically .

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking for the same thing. All I can find after hours of searching are just plain circles and node connected by dull lines. I came however upon this tool which seems to be rather advanced in displaying RDF information. I haven't looked deep into it yet, but it looks promising:

http://cytoscape.org/

Comment: Cytoscape doesn't support RDF.

Comment: https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/rdfscsape

Answer (score 4):

i am looking for pretty much the same thing.  lots of googling, and reading of phd articles, lead me to a few possibilities.

- [Javascript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/)
- [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/)

definitely would be interested in whatever others may have found, or are using.

Comment: alternatively, there are also these resources:
 - [WP5 / LOD2](http://lod2.eu/WorkPackage/wp5.html) (entire framework)
 - [Periodic Table of Visualization Methods](http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html) (general reference)