# How to draw a RDF design diagram

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I'm learning about the Jena RDF API ,and I have saw some RDF was shown in a diagram like this
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBvaA.png).
I want to know how to draw the picture like that,are there any W3C standards or tools about drawing the diagram? for example,what do the ellipse and the rectangle represent for.
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rdf+visualization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Great RDF visualization tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975239/great-rdf-visualization-tools)

Comment: are there any standars or org to draw the diagram？

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand you don't want to find an RDF visualizer, but instead you are interested in a tool that can easily draw RDF graphs.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a good tool either. For drawing simple diagrams I typically use draw.io, while for creating ontology diagrams I use [Graffoo](https://essepuntato.it/graffoo/).

Hope this helps.